# Ruby 1.9.2-p290 through rbenv produces warning from psych-1.2.1: VERSION and LIBYAML_VERSION

Tags: ruby, warnings, psych

When I running ruby I get the following warnings:

```
~/.gem/gems/psych-1.2.1/lib/psych.rb:93: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
~/.gem/gems/psych-1.2.1/lib/psych.rb:96: warning: already initialized constant LIBYAML_VERSION
```

I've tried googling around but can seem to find a solution which makes me think it's specific to my system. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to originate in psych being called by bundler in Bundler.setup. The work-around I used:

```
gem 'psych'
```

In my code before

```
Bundler.setup
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

->First

> add gem 'psych'

in your Gemfile file and then run

> bundle install

-> Second

> gem uninstall psych

at console